# CFBuilder 2 insert closing tag does not work

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I am using CFBuilder 2 (free version) and the insert closing tag functionality does not seem to work.

Here are my settings:-
[image]

Now if I type in a new openning tag e.g. `<cfscript>` I never get the closing tag. Am I misunderstanding what it is supposed to do or is there some other setting I should be changing?

This worked well in cfeclipse and so is incredibly frustrating.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the "typing" preferences page.  There is a setting called: "auto-close tags".  You probably have this set to "never".  Try setting it to "When typing '>' of start tag".  See attached image:

[image: Example of "Typing" preferences page]